# Regex to match and replace **someVal** in to <b>someVal</b>

Tags: regex, freemarker

**I have the following input:**

```
**1** Blah  **3** Blah
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<b>1</b> Blah  <b>3</b> Blah
```

Basically I'm trying to use the following regex with free marker to replace leading ** with <b> and </b>

```
/\*\*([^\*]+)\*\*
```

https://regex101.com/r/aX0xL6/2

I'm a bit confused on how to replace the ** for an according <b> or </b>....then I need to figure it out in freemarker.

Comment: which language you are using?

Comment: in the end it will be free marker but just to start somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work better than the regex you've already posted.

```
\*{2}(.+?)\*{2}
```

The substitution code is:

```
<b>$1</b>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aX0xL6/3

Comment: wow, very nice!  impressive!  seems so simple once you see it.  =)  awesome solution.  thanks!